# Am I using the getch() function from the ncurses library incorrectly?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am writing a Pacman game in c++ using the ncurses library, but I am not able to move the Pacman properly. I have used `getch()` to move it it up, down, left and right, but it only moves right and does not move anywhere else when I press any other key.

This is a code snippet for moving up. I have written similar code with some conditions altered accordingly for moving left, right and down.

```cpp
int ch = getch(); 
if (ch == KEY_RIGHT)
{
  int i,row,column;
  //getting position of cursor by getyx function
  for (i=column; i<=last_column; i+=2)
  {
    //time interval of 1 sec

    mvprintw(row,b,"<");   //print < in given (b,row) coordinates

    //time interval of 1 sec

    mvprintw(row,(b+1),"O");  //print "O" next to "<"
    int h = getch();   //to give the option for pressing another key 
    if (h != KEY_RIGHT)  //break current loop if another key is pressed
    {
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (condition)
{
  //code to move left
}
```

Am I using getch() wrong, or is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

Many of the "special" keys on a keyboard -- Up, Down, Left, Right, Home, End, Function keys, etc. actually return two scan codes from the keyboard controller back to the CPU. The "standard" keys all return one. So if you want to check for special keys, you'll need to call getch() twice.

For example up arrow is  first 224, then 72.

Comment: So  i need to store both the values and check by if statement if they are equal to up arrow.

Comment: Have you checked the values of getch()?

Comment: i did this                                                                   ch=getch();                                                         ch1=getch();                                                         if (ch==KEY_RIGHT && ch1==KEY_RIGHT)    //same with moving left code

Comment: but what are the values of ch,ch1?

Comment: actually the real problem seems to be is that only the first if statement is working.others are not.

Answer (score 0):

`261` is consistent with `KEY_RIGHT` (octal `0405` in `curses.h`).  That tells us at least that `keypad` was used to allow `getch` to read special keys.

The fragment shown doesn't give clues to how it was incorporated into the rest of the program.  However, the use of `getch` in a loop is likely a source of confusion, since on exiting the loop the value is discarded.  If you expect to do something different (from `KEY_RIGHT`), you could use `ungetch` to save the (otherwise discarded) value within the loop, e.g.,

```
if (h != KEY_RIGHT)  //break current loop if another key is pressed
{
  ungetch(h);     //added
  break;
}
```

Doing that will allow the *next* call to `getch` to return the key which exits the loop.